# Deploying Sagemaker Neo compiled model on JetPack 4.6

Tags: python

Could you please confirm on can we deploy a Sagemaker Neo compiled model on Jetpack 4.6 and run inference? Device : Nvidia Jetson TX2 with Jetpack 4.6 And also confirm the required DLR version and Jetson versions supported by Sagemaker neo models. Please share reference documents.

Thanks,

1.Could'nt able to  deploy a Sagemaker Neo compiled model on Jetpack 4.6
Reference:
https://github.com/neo-ai/neo-ai-dlr/blob/main/sagemaker-neo-notebooks/edge/jetson-xavier/neo-xavier-object-detection.ipynb
Instead xavier we used Tx2 above notebook.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.